# Django count object calls

Tags: django

How do I count the calls of an object. For example: I have an Image app and I want to show users how often a picture was called. Like the videoviews on youtube

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store a count in the table and increment it each time you use the image.

First, add a field to your model if you don't have one already to store the count:

```
class MyImageClass(models.Model):
    ...
    views = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

You'll then need to create a view that will return the image data and increment the view count.

```
def my_image_view(request, id):
    instance = get_object_or_404(MyImageClass, id=id)

    filename, ext = os.path.splitext(instance.image_field.name)
    ext = ext[1:].lower() # remove period and normalize to lowercase

    instance.views += 1
    instance.save()

    response = HttpResponse(instance.image_field.read(), mimetype='image/%s' % ext)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline;filename=%s.%s' % (filename, ext)
    return response
```

Hook the view into a urlpattern, and then in your template call the image with:

```
<img src="{% url my_image_view_name id=my_image.id %}">
```

You'll surely have to do some optimization with that, and there's thread-safety issues to consider, but that's enough to get the ball rolling for you.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any built in method to allow this.  You will have to store the information into the database